# having trouble sending messages with the Chrome API for an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The project I am working on is an extension that displays the 5 most popular colors on a specific webpage.

The issue that I am having is that when I click the "Get Palette" button, I want it to regrab all of the colors of the current page we're on. However, it just remains as what it was previously. For example, if I "Get Palette" on an initial page, it works but when I switch tabs or open a new page and press the button again, it only displays the colors from the previous output.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Color Palette</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Color Palette</h1>
    <button id="get-palette">Get Palette</button>
    <main id="output"></main>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const btn = document.getElementById('get-palette')
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        populateColors();
    })
});

function populateColors() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ method: "getColors" }, function (response) {
        // From response, get top colors and display

        const colorCounts = {};
        response.forEach((color) => {
            colorCounts[color] = (colorCounts[color] || 0) + 1;
        });
        const sortedColors = Object.keys(colorCounts).sort(
            (a, b) => colorCounts[b] - colorCounts[a]
        );

        // Create blocks of the most frequent colors
        const colorsContainer = document.getElementById("output");
        for (let i = 0; i < 5 && i < sortedColors.length; i++) {
            const colorBlock = document.createElement("div");
            colorBlock.style.backgroundColor = sortedColors[i];
            colorBlock.style.width = "50px";
            colorBlock.style.height = "50px";
            colorBlock.style.margin = "5px";
            colorBlock.style.border = "1px solid black";
            colorsContainer.appendChild(colorBlock);
        }
    });
}
```

**background.js**

```
let colors = [];
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // When we get a message from the content script
    if (message.method == 'setColors') {
        colors = message.colors;
        console.log('Colors set:', colors);
    }
    // When we get a message from the popup
    else if (message.method == 'getColors') {
        sendResponse(colors);
        console.log('Colors sent:', colors);
    }
});
```

**content_script.js**

```
// Function to convert RGB color to HEX format
function rgbToHex(rgb) {
    const rgbValues = rgb.match(/\d+/g);
    const r = parseInt(rgbValues[0]);
    const g = parseInt(rgbValues[1]);
    const b = parseInt(rgbValues[2]);
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}

function renderColors() {
    // Regular expression to match colors in CSS
    const colorRegex = /#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}\b|\b((rgb|hsl)a?\([\d\s%,.]+\))/gi;

    // Array to store the color values
    const colors = [];

    // Get all the link elements on the page
    const links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

    // Loop through the links and process the CSS files
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        const link = links[i];
        // Only process link elements with rel="stylesheet"
        if (link.rel === 'stylesheet') {
            // Use the Fetch API to fetch the CSS file
            fetch(link.href)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(cssText => {
                    // Parse the CSS file and process it
                    const colorValues = cssText.match(colorRegex);
                    if (colorValues) {
                        colorValues.forEach(colorValue => {
                            // Check if the color is in RGB format
                            if (colorValue.startsWith("rgb")) {
                                const hexValue = rgbToHex(colorValue);
                                colors.push(hexValue);
                            } else {
                                colors.push(colorValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //console.log(`FROM CONTENT SCRIPT: ${colors}`)
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ 'method': 'setColors', 'colors': colors });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching CSS file:', error);
                });
        }
    }

}

renderColors();
```

Comment: Please debug using DevTools.

Comment: The simplest solution is to remove background.js and messaging, then use executeScript to run the code on demand, [example](/a/67227376).